# How Can I Test The Basic AppMention Event Using Salesforce SDK for Slack?

Tags: apex, unit-test, slack

I'm working with [Salesforce Slack SDK](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/salesforce-slack-sdk/overview), but I don't understand how can I test the **app_mention** event due to there are no examples and the documentation is not clear at all, I request help for test this event.

This is the code for to handle the event when the app mention in any Slack Channel

```
public class AppMentioned extends Slack.EventDispatcher {

public override Slack.ActionHandler invoke(Slack.EventParameters parameters, Slack.RequestContext context) {
    return Slack.ActionHandler.ack(new Handler(parameters, context));
}

public class Handler implements Slack.RunnableHandler {
    Slack.EventParameters parameters;
    Slack.RequestContext context;

    public Handler(Slack.EventParameters parameters, Slack.RequestContext context) {
        this.parameters = parameters;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            // Name must match the DeveloperName of your SlackApp.
            Slack.App app = Slack.App.MyApp.get();
            Slack.BotClient botClient = app.getBotClientForTeam(context.getTeamId());
            Slack.AppMentionEvent appMentionEvent = (Slack.AppMentionEvent) parameters.getEvent();
            String channel = appMentionEvent.getChannel();
            String appMentionMessage = appMentionEvent.getText().replaceAll('<[^>]*>', '').trim();
            String ts = appMentionEvent.getTs();
            String threadTs = appMentionEvent.getThreadTs();

            handleOpenAI(channel, appMentionMessage, ts, threadTs);

            Slack.ChatPostMessageResponse response = botClient.chatPostMessage(
                    Slack.ChatPostMessageRequest.builder().channel(channel).text(appMentionMessage).threadTs(ts).build()
            );

            System.debug(response);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    private void handleOpenAI(String channel, String message, String ts, String threadTs) {
        ChainComposer chain = new ChainComposer(channel, message, ts, threadTs);
        chain.doWork();
    }
}

public static String createThread() {
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://api.openai.com/v1/threads');
    request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer mybearertokenhere');
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('OpenAI-Beta', 'assistants=v1');
    request.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

    Map<String, Object> responseMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
    return (String) responseMap.get('id');
}


public static void createMessageInThread(String threadId, String content) {
    /* Create the message for the created thread */
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://api.openai.com/v1/threads/' + threadId + '/messages');
    request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer mybearertokenhere');
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('OpenAI-Beta', 'assistants=v1');
    request.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    Map<String, Object> jsonRequest1 = new Map<String, Object>{
            'role' => 'user',
            'content' => content
    };
    request.setBody(JSON.serialize(jsonRequest1));

    http.send(request);
}


public static void createRunInThread(String threadId) {
    /* Create the message for the created thread */
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://api.openai.com/v1/threads/' + threadId + '/runs');
    request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer mybearertokenhere');
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('OpenAI-Beta', 'assistants=v1');
    request.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    Map<String, Object> jsonRequest = new Map<String, Object>{
            'stream' => true,
            'assistant_id' => 'myassistantid'
    };
    request.setBody(JSON.serialize(jsonRequest));

    http.send(request);
}


public static String retrieveThreadMessages(String threadId) {
    /* Create the message for the created thread */
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://api.openai.com/v1/threads/' + threadId + '/messages');
    request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer mybearertokenhere');
    request.setMethod('GET');
    request.setHeader('OpenAI-Beta', 'assistants=v1');
    request.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
    Map<String, Object> responseMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());

    String latestAssistantResult = '';
    List<Object> messages = (List<Object>) responseMap.get('data');
    for (Object messageObj : messages) {
        Map<String, Object> message = (Map<String, Object>) messageObj;

        if (message.get('role') == 'assistant') {
            Map<String, Object> content = (Map<String, Object>) ((List<Object>) message.get('content'))[0];
            Map<String, Object> text = (Map<String, Object>) content.get('text');

            latestAssistantResult = (String) text.get('value');
            break;
        }
    }

    return latestAssistantResult;
}

public static void sendSlackMessage(String channelId, String message, String ts) {
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage');
    request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer mybottokenhere);
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    Map<String, Object> jsonRequest = new Map<String, Object>{
            'thread_ts' => ts,
            'channel' => channelId,
            'text' => message,
            'mrkdwn' => true
    };
    request.setBody(JSON.serialize(jsonRequest));

    http.send(request);
}
}
```

Is not necessary to test the callouts because I'll move those functions to another class with their own test class, I just want to know about the mention event to test.